# htaccess RewriteCond wildcard and strip

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Example URL's:

```
 http://example.com/guest/book3/book21.php?title.htm
 http://example.com/guest/book391/book418.php?title.htm
 http://example.com/guest/book15/book1049.php?title.htm
```

These all need to redirect to one URL:

```
http://example.com/new/
```

We need to strip everything from the URL and just redirect directly to the URL.

I have this but failing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/guest/book([0-9]+)$/book([0-9]+)$.php
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}/new/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `RewriteCond` as you can do this in `RewriteRule` itself:

```
RewriteRule ^guest/book\d+/book\d+ /new/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

`?` in the end will strip off previous query string.